# qt5 namespace Ui

Tags: c++, qt5

```
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}
```

объясните пожалуйста, эти строчки. они в каждом проекте на qt5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это предварительное объявление класса. Это значит, что `MainWindow` может быть использовано в таких контекстах, где размер объекта типа `MainWindow` не играет роли(например при объявлении указателей `MainWindow*`). Т.к. `MainWindow` находится в пространстве имён `Ui`, требуется и предварительное объявление поместить в это пространство имён.